Interpretation of spectral function for Anomalous Green Function
This question assumes we have quasi-particles which can be diagonalized by a BV transformation (here I am using imaginary time and I am in position space):
$$        \hat{c}_{i\sigma}(\tau)
        =
        e^{\tau E_l}
        e^{i\varphi}
        v^*_{il}
        \hat{b}_l^\dagger
        +
        \sigma
        e^{-\tau E_l}
        u_{il}\hat{b}_l$$
Where I defined quasi particle operators $\hat{b}_l$ which create excitation of energy $E_l$. The coefficients are the coherence factors.
In a BCS like state we can calculate the following anomalous Green function:
$$        F^T_{i}(\tau)
        =
        -\langle{T_\tau\big(
        \hat{c}_{i\sigma}(\tau)
        \hat{c}_{i\sigma}
        \big)}\rangle $$
This is clearly related to the BCS gap. If we take a FT, then we can express our Green functino in the following spectral representation:
$$ 
        {F}^{T}_{i}(i\tilde{\omega}_n)
        =
        \frac{1}{\beta}
        \int_0^\beta d\tau\;
        e^{i\tilde{\omega}_n\tau}
        {F}^{T}_{i}(\tau)
        =
        \frac{1}{\beta}
        \int d\omega 
        \frac{1}{i\tilde{\omega}_n-\omega}
        \sum_{E_l\geq 0}
        u_{il}v^*_{il}
        \Big(
        \delta(\omega+E_l)
        -
        \delta(\omega-E_l)
        \Big)
        =
        \frac{1}{\beta}
        \int d\omega 
        \frac{B_{i}(\omega)}{i\tilde{\omega}_n-\omega}
$$
Where I defined:
$$ B_{i}(\omega)
=
        \sum_{E_l\geq 0}
        u_{il}v^*_{il}
        \Big(
        \delta(\omega+E_l)
        -
        \delta(\omega-E_l)
        \Big)
$$
This is very similar to the BCS gap equation except for the delta functions. In the case of the normal Green function the spectral function is the local-density-of-states (LDOS) and it tells you the number of states per unit energy at a particular location.
**My question is:**What does this function physically tell us? Something about the pair density I am guessing, but unlike the LDOS it is complex. Can I extract any information out of this directly like the LDOS? Do the real and imaginary parts tell you anything different? What about the absolute value and the argument of the phase?
Any sort of clarification would be great!

the absolute value of F is related to the magnitude of the pairing correlation, while its phase to the phase coherence of the cooper pairs. Unlike with G, its imaginary part (numerator in the spectral representation) does not tell you much about single particle excitation, it's more about pairing correlation. If there's anything more to it I'm not aware
